# NHibernate transaction not working properly on Postgres

Tags: c#, postgresql, nhibernate, transactions

I have common dll referenced by desktop application and web application. One of the methods creates 3 objects and inserts them into DB within transaction.

However, when I call this method at the same time from web application and desktop application, objects are not inserted 3by3...their order is mixed (1 from desktop application, followed by 1 from web application, etc).

Is my code ok?Is there something to do with mapping, or nhibernate cfg???
Thank you very much in advance.

```
               Notifications not = new Notifications();
               not.Notes = applicationName;
               not.GeneratedTime = DateTime.Now;
               using (var session = SessionManager.OpenSession())
               using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
               {
                   // do what you need to do with the session
                   session.Save(not);

               not = new Notifications();
               not.Notes = applicationName;
               not.GeneratedTime = DateTime.Now;

                   session.Save(not);

               not = new Notifications();
               not.Notes = applicationName;
               not.GeneratedTime = DateTime.Now;

                   // do what you need to do with the session
                   session.Save(not);
                   transaction.Commit();
               }
```

Comment: Rows in a relational database are ***NOT*** "sorted". The order in which they are stored is completely irrelevant. Just make sure you apply the approriate `ORDER BY` when *retrieving* the data. This could be done using e.g. a timestamp column that stores the time when the row was inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are under the incorrect assumption that performing inserts in one transaction will prevent inserts from happening in other concurrent transactions.

This is just not true (unless you use some specific transaction isolation level, exclusively lock the whole table, etc... but let's just say it's not true)